# ERROR while implementing Cox PH model for recurrent event survival analysis using counting process

Tags: recurrence

I have been trying to run Cox PH model on a sample data set of 10k customers (randomly taken from 32 million customer base) for predicting probability of survival in time t (which is month in my case). I am using **recurrent event survival analysis** using **counting process** for e-commerce. For this...
1. Observation starting point: right after a customer makes first purchase
2. Start/Stop times: Months of two consecutive purchases (as in the data)

I have a few independent variables as in the sample data below:

```
id  start   stop    status  tenure  orders  revenue   Quantity
A       0   20      0          0      1       $89.0     1
B       0   17      0          0      1      $556.0     2
C       0   17      0          0      1      $900.0     2
D      32   33      0       1679      9      $357.8     9
D      26   32      1       1497      7      $326.8     7
D      23   26      1       1405      4      $142.9     4
D      17   23      1       1219      3       $63.9 3
D       9   17      1        978      2       $50.0     2         
D       0    9      1        694      1       $35.0     1
E       0   15      0         28      2      $156.0      2
F       0   15      0          0      1      $348.0     1
F      12   14      0        375      2      $216.8     3
F       0   12      1          0      1       $67.8     2
G       9   15      0        277      2      $419.0      2
G       0    9      1          0      1      $359.0      1
```

While running cox PH using the following code:

```
fit10=coxph(Surv(start,stop,status)~orders+tenure+Quantity+revenue,data=test)
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
    Warning: X matrix deemed to be singular; variable 1 2 3 4
```

I tried searching for the same error online but the answers I found said this could be because of interacting independent variables, whereas my variables are individual and continuous.